# python 2.7 TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is my code

```
message = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr
        + "To: %s\r\n" % toaddrs
        + "CC: %s\r\n" % ",".join(cc)
        + "Subject: %s\r\n" % message_subject
        + "\r\n" 
        + msg
```

i am getting this error:

```
    + "To: %s\r\n" % toaddrs
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

may you help please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix your problem, wrap the whole expression for message in parenthesies:

```
message = (
      "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr
    + "To: %s\r\n" % toaddrs
    + "CC: %s\r\n" % ",".join(cc)
    + "Subject: %s\r\n" % message_subject
    + "\r\n" 
    + msg
)
```

The error message python is giving is quite helpful.  Unary operations are those with exactly one argument.  + can be used as a unary operation in python,

```
x = + 2
```

is valid code.  What's happening in your snippet is that the first line:

```
message = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr
```

is being interpreted as a full assignment statement.  The next line starts a new statement, but is incomplete.